# How mask the value in nested xml tag

Tags: deserialization, masking

I have a .NET code which mask the value and shows the output in xml logs but now I want the mask repeated values. Below code mask only name but I want to mask phone no too.

```
private static string GetXmlTagValue(string inputString, string xmlTagToFind)
{
    var regExPattern = $"<{xmlTagToFind} .*?>(.*?)</{xmlTagToFind}>|<{xmlTagToFind}>(.*?)</{xmlTagToFind}>";
    var match = Regex.Match(inputString, regExPattern);
    return match.Success ? XElement.Parse(match.Value).Value : string.Empty;
}

private static string mask(this string inputValue)
{
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputValue)
          ? inputValue : "".PadLeft(inputValue.Trim().Length, 'X');
}

private static StringBuilder Deserialize(StringBuilder inputString)
{
    var key= GetXmlTagValue(inputString.ToString(), "key");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
      inputString = inputString.Replace(key, key.mask())
    return inputString;
}
```